# Passing unique_ptr instead of * to method

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a POD I use as a `unique_ptr` and lldb tells me its of type `POD *`.
I have a free floating function I'd like to pass a reference of this POD to so I can populate public properties.

If I add a parameter of type `POD *` to the function, Clang has no problems compiling my code but if I try to pass `unique_ptr<POD> &param` or `unique_ptr<POD param` it fails with:

`Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from ' *' to 'unique_ptr<>'`

I thought I could always pass a `unique_ptr` where I'd have a raw pointer and vice-versa?

**Update, method signature:**

Original:

```
void connection_fsm(const LogLevel &level, const bytes &barray, unique_ptr<PGOutput> &output) noexcept;
```

vs

```
void connection_fsm(const LogLevel &level, const bytes &barray, unique_ptr<Conn> &conn, unique_ptr<PGOutput> &output) noexcept;
```

vs

```
void connection_fsm(const LogLevel &level, const bytes &barray, unique_ptr<Conn> conn, unique_ptr<PGOutput> &output) noexcept;
```

vs

```
void connection_fsm(const LogLevel &level, const bytes &barray, Conn *conn, unique_ptr<PGOutput> &output) noexcept;
```

Comment: You can always pass raw pointersaround  as required using `std::unique_ptr::get()`. There's usually no harm regarding that.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: example of code, please

Comment: To answer the only statement in your question with a question mark:  You thought wrong.

Comment: Never pass a unique_ptr to a function, if you do not want to transfer ownership. Your assumption is wrong, you can not mix both. Use unique_ptr::get to get a raw pointer. That saiid: show code!

Comment: Using the raw-pointers from RAII-smart pointers is usually not recommended. There's a reason to use the encapsulated memory and wrap it in some restrictive behaviour. But as @user5821508 said: Please provide at least the fully qualified signature of the function.

Comment: The most common mistake, and this appears to be no exception, is to take a `unique_ptr<T>`  when a `T&` or `T const&` is meant. That is to say, here the caller probably needs a `PGoutput&`. Don't pass a `PGouput*` unless you intend to accept `nullptr`.

Comment: @MSalters what if T is already defined as a *?

Comment: @ruipacheco: If `T` is an `U*`, then `T&` is an `U*&`. But a `std::unique_ptr<U*>` is quite suspicious. That means `U*` itself is deleted when the smart pointer goes out of scope, but the `U` object pointer to is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unique_ptr` implies ownership. Are you transferring ownership? If not, do not pass `unique_ptr`. Remember that `unique_ptr` will delete the underlying object on destruction. For this reason it is also not copyable (it makes no sense to have a copy of something unique).

There is nothing wrong with passing raw pointers around, as long as their lifetime extends beyond the lifetime of the method being called.

Passing a reference to a `unique_ptr` adds no value to just passing a raw pointer. Finally, it didn't work for you because it's not possible to bind a temporary (rvalue) to an lvalue reference.

Comment: Not only passing a reference to `unique_ptr` adds no value, but it forces a memory management model onto the caller. Pointlessly, since it doesn't care about how the caller got the object, just that it remains valid.

Answer (score 2):

The available conversion from a raw pointer to an unique pointer is this constructor:

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

As that constructor is marked `explicit` it is not considered for *implicit* conversions.

And that's good, because if we force the conversion like that:

```
T * raw = get_it_from_somewhere ();
// Assume function takes unique_ptr by value or reference
function(std::unique_ptr<T>{raw});
//              ^^ a temporary
delete raw;
```

Then the temporary unique pointer will **take ownership of the pointed to object** and thus *delete* it after the function call! Thus with above code you get a double delete (and of course cannot dereference that pointer after the function call).

Now that's fine if you intend to pass ownership to that `function`, but otherwise you shouldn't use an unique pointer. Better pass a (if possible `const` ) reference or (if you need "nullable" behavior) a raw pointer.

Comment: Yes, because in order to reference a unique pointer, you first have to actually have a unique pointer. Thus, if `function` takes a reference, a *temporary* will be constructed.

Comment: Unfortunately the remark of using a const reference comes in the end, which is an important indication of usage and yields a very good code-style. However, it is in my opinion absolutely no problem to pass around a const reference to a `unique_ptr<T>`, if `read-only & not-storing`-access is intended to extract some information. The ownership is not of interest while reading  some data from the connection. If the connectionmanager still has the original `unique_ptr<T>` it will also remain valid, unless one does some really weird * * * *.

Comment: @MABVT passing a reference to an unique pointer makes `function` less general for no benefit (try to use function with an object with automatic storage then ... e.g. `T obj; function (obj);`)

Comment: @DanielJour In his case, he wants to pass around a connection-instance, which should not be writable from everywhere, so this is a very specific case, in which using a `const std::unique_ptr<Conn>&` is his best deal in giving so much semantic significance to make clear what's the use case. Of course, in a multipurpose function, which should work for an arbitrary amount of types passed in, hardcoding the signature to a unique_ptr<T> is not necessarily reasonable. But passing around raw-pointers, which someone intended to be protected and managed in specific ways just breaks....